# Symfony 2 fresh windows install - web folder permissions issue

Tags: windows, apache, symfony, permissions, assetic

I encounter a problem with my symfony setup.

In fact, I can access at my project in local (which is a clone of a working repo) but css and js seems broken as you can see :

[image: console]

I'm on windows 10, the web symlink looks ok (files are here), this is my vhost :

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName local.franckfurt
  ServerAlias local.franckfurt
  DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/.../web
  <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/...">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride all
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried add umask(0002); line in my app files and console without success, use git bash for chmod 775 command on web repository and some other things I already missed.

Thanks in advance for yout time,

Kupris

Comment: Did you run `php app/console assets:install web`

Comment: When you ran the assets:install command did those files and folders get put into the `<site>/web/bundles/*` folders? and if so what are the permissions on those?

Comment: There're all presents in web folder. For permissions, does I must check windows permissions or use a unix bash to see them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I activate administrator account, change windows permissions for users and after clearing cache it works.
Don't know if it's the best solution but it works for now.
Thanks for all your replys.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

`Require All Granted`

Instead of `Require local`

And take a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html for extra upgrade info.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I replace "Order Allow,Deny Allow from All Require local" by "Require All Granted" and then restart apache, nothing happened, 403 forbidden always show up. If I check the doc, it looks like ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot `install assets`:

```
php app/console assets:install web
```

http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/best_practices/web-assets.html

Answer (score 0):

Your directory should match your DocumentRoot

```
DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/.../web
<Directory "C:/wamp64/www/.../web">
```

Notice the `web` in the `<Directory >`

http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: I did it, I just forgot keeping web directory when I remove the project name.